# Getting Exception on using 'DataProcSparkOperator' in Airflow Dags

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow

I am very new for Apache Airflow Usage, currently using Airflow1.10.4 with Python 2.7 support.
I need to trigger a spark job via Airflow DAG, so using 'DataProcSparkOperator'. But facing exception

> AttributeError: 'DataProcSparkOperator' object has no attribute 'dataproc_spark_jars'

Code snippet:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataProcSparkOperator
.
.
.
data_t1 = DataProcSparkOperator(
    task_id='data_job',
    job_name='extract_data',
    cluster_name='cluster-a',
    arguments=["{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='puller') }}","gs://data-bucket/dailydata"],
    main_jar='gs://data-bucket/spark_jar1/spark-read-5.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar',
    region="us-central",
    dag=dag
)
```

Tried with main_jar / dataproc_spark_jars attribute (all possible ways)
However, I tried with other fixes suggested(as airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator is deprecated in some versions), hence used below

```
from airflow.gcp.operators.dataproc import DataProcSparkOperator
```

again I am facing

> Import Error: No module gcp.operators.dataproc..

Comment: Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: Hi All, Resolved the issue by upgrading airflow version to 1.10.6. Hope it may help. Thanks.